# Insert 1D NumPy array as column in existing 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `2D` `NumPy` array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

and a `1D` array:

```
>>> b = np.arange(3)
>>> b
array([0, 1, 2])
```

Is there an elegant way to insert `b` into `a` as a new first column?

So that:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `column_stack()`

```
In [256]: np.column_stack((b, a))
Out[256]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 7, 8, 9]])
```